# pattern in java 1234 2341 3421 4321 1234 2341 ...n rows

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

```
package programs500;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pattern1234_2341 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=s.nextInt();
        int t=0;
         
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            int count=1;
            t=i; 
            if (i>4)
            {
                t=i-4;
            }
                
            for(int j=t;j<=4;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(j + " ");
                count++;                
            }
            int k=1;
                        
            while(count<=4)
            {
                System.out.print(k + " ");
                k++;
                count++;                
            }
                        
            System.out.println();
        }       
    }
}
```

Q- My code is executing the pattern till n=9. Can anyone help for for n>9 numbers?

Comment: Can't you just substring the first number and put it on the back

Comment: Before trying to change the code to handle values of `n` above 9, you should fix the code to actually print the pattern shown in the title. 3rd and 4th output is different, e.g. 4th is `4 1 2 3`, but the title shows `4 3 2 1`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code only works for `i` in range 1-8.

```java
t=i;
if (i>4)
{
    t=i-4;
}
```

If you change the two `i`'s to `t`'s, and make it a loop, the code can handle larger values.

```java
t=i;
while (t>4)
{
    t=t-4;
}
```

Instead of a loop, you should however use the remainder operator (`%`).

```java
t = (i - 1) % 4 + 1;
```